# Что вернет isAlive() у потока который уже start() но еще не run()?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня ситуация при которой после вызова `start()` поток начинает проверяться на `isAlive()`, но учитывая что мы точно не знаем когда `run()` вызовется, возникает вопрос: А что если первая проверка на `isAlive()` произойдет между вызовами `start()` и `run()`?

Результат будет `true` или `false`?

Comment: Откуда вы будете вызывать isAlive? Из другого потока? Или из основного, в том котором стартует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из документации:

> A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Поток стартует после вызова метода `start()`, и умирает после того, как завершается выполнение `run()` или вызывается метод `stop()`. Т.о. после вызова `start()` проверка `isAlive()` вернет `true`.